# Rewrite to a subdirectory with MVC support

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

Basically, I am working on a site which lives within a directory on another site - meaning I have no access to the host files. I am trying to mimic the usual website structure of `public_html` and `private` folders.

So I need `mydir` directory to redirect to `public` directory.
I also need this to support MVC architecture.

I currently have the following:

Inside `mydir` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mydir/public/ 
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ /mydir/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Inside `public` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /mydir/public/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

For the most part this works fine, however I have duplicate directories.
e.g. `/mydir/` is the same as `/mydir/public`.

In case I've explained this poorly, here are a few example of what I'm trying to do:

- `/mydir/index.php` -> `/mydir/`
- `/mydir/blog/` -> `/mydir/public/blog/`

Comment: You're talking about `main` and `public` directories but what about `mydir` directory ? Anyway, you can do what you want with only one rule in main directory's htaccess (others become useless)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean for that. Also, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Taking your comment into account, the solution would be to have only an htaccess in `mydir` with this rule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydir/public/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: It doesn't look like you've read my entire question; because that does not solve my issues. That's less of what I already had :3

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has seeming fixed my issues:

This was my only `.htaccess` file and it was inside the `mydir` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /webapps/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/index.php?path=$1 [L,NC]
```